# How to make the provider rebuilding only certain widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am a newbie in in provider and i have 2 question regarding of rebuild tree

i have this class

```
class Myprovider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isFound= false;

  bool get isFoundM=> isFound;

  void changeStatus(bool status){
    isFound= status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and i have `stfl`widget which contains the following code under `build method`

```
 Myprovider myProvider = Myprovider ();
    Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: myProvider.isFound?  MainAxisAlignment.center: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children:[

          myProvider.isFound? const Text('Hello flutter'):Container(),

          const Text('Hello dart'),

          TextButton(
              onPressed:(){
                myProvider.changeStatus(true);
              },

              child: Text('tab me')
          )

        ]
    );
```

1- when i tab the Button , is Hello flutter Text only will only rebuilt its self or the whole tree will be rebuild ?

2- what about the widgets property in my column above ? .. it will only rebuilt the property even if it's parent was wrapping several widgets ?

if no How can i handle this

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stateful widget has nothing to do with provider.

*Stateful Widget are only useful when you are working with SetState. Where every widget under build context get updated and it will not help you to update any certain widgets*

**Building certain widgets with provider**

*When working with provider you can build certain widgets with out rebuilding the whole content*

For that you can use **Consumer**

```
Foo(
  child: Consumer<A>(
    builder: (_, a, child) {
      return Bar(a: a, child: child);
    },
    child: Baz(),
  ),
)
```

*NB:-In this example, only Bar will rebuild when A updates. Foo and Baz won't unnecessarily rebuild.*

Comment: thanks ,  but even if i use Consumer into Stateful widget .? nothing to do? and what about widgets property ?

Comment: you don't need to use stateful widget when using any type of state management library. you can go with stateless widget every thing works fine .Thank you

Comment: but i tested Consumer into stfl widget and updated a widget , so the result was that any widget out the consumer didn't update , and the widget into consumer  updated successful , any notse?

Comment: yes everything only inside the consumer will only get update. and don't mix the stateless and stateful concepts here, you don't want to use stateful widget when using any state management library. so you need to specify consumer in the last widget of the where you want to update. if you do want to use multiple consumer you can put a consumer at the top of the widget tree. which is not a best way

Comment: thanks Alan , i understand you as well , but i think you misunderstood me here ,, i tested Consumer into Stfl widget and i made update , the result was that the consumer widget is the only one who rebuilt , that's mean it is rebuilt it's self only and not the whole tree , and if it rebuilt only it's child why don't use it into stfl like always

Comment: i mean this was my need to rebuilding only one widget , when you advice me to not use stfl widget i thought any update for a consumer it will update the whole widget  and not only it's child ,, but when i tested it it is updated its child only and that's cool

Comment: sorry i mean it's return not child *

Comment: ok have you fixed everything?

Comment: yes thank you . and will be thankful if you told me why not good to use consumer within Stfl if it really can rebuild one widget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242296/discussion-between-alan-bosco-and-jack).